# Image array in rock,paper, scissors game

Tags: javascript

```js
const rock = document.getElementById('rock')
const paper = document.getElementById('paper')
const scissors = document.getElementById('scissors')

rock.addEventListener('click', function(){
    userImg.src = "img/rock.png"
    cpuPick()
})
paper.addEventListener('click', function(){
    userImg.src = "img/paper.png"
    cpuPick()
})
scissors.addEventListener('click', function(){
    userImg.src = "img/scissors.png"
    cpuPick()
})

let imgArray = new Array();

imgArray[0] = new Image();
imgArray[0].src = 'img/rock.png'

imgArray[1] = new Image();
imgArray[1].src = 'img/paper.png'

imgArray[2] = new Image();
imgArray[2].src = 'img/scissors.png'

function cpuPick(){
    compImg.src = imgArray[Math.floor(imgArray.length * Math.random())]
}
```

```html
    <div class="overview">
        <div class="userSide">
            <h4>User:</h4><span> 2</span>
            <img id="userImg" src="img/Paper.png" style="width: 220px; height: 220px;">
        </div>
        <div class="compSide">
            <h4>CPU:</h4><span> 2</span>
            <img id="compImg" src="img/Paper.png" style="width: 220px; height: 220px;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="userBTN">
        <button id="rock">Rock</button>
        <button id="paper">Paper</button>
        <button id="scissors">Scissors</button>
    </div>
```

I am making a javascript rock, paper, scissors game and trying to pass the function "cpuPick()" as soon as the user presses on a button to take his pick. Currently, if the user clicks on 'Rock' the image of rock will show on the user side but the CPU image will disappear as if it can't read it. Where is my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you assign the src, you have to assign the `src`, not the image itself.

So, replace

```
compImg.src = imgArray[Math.floor(imgArray.length * Math.random())]
```

with

```
compImg.src = imgArray[Math.floor(imgArray.length * Math.random())].src;
```

...and what you have will work.

---

Note what you currently have can be simplified to:

```js
const images = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];

const makeImageUrl = id => `img/${id}.png`;

document.querySelector('.userBTN').addEventListener('click', e => {
  const id = e.target.closest('button')?.id;
  if (id && images.includes(id)) {
    userImg.src = makeImageUrl(id);
    cpuPick();
  }
})

function cpuPick() {
  compImg.src = makeImageUrl(images[Math.floor(images.length * Math.random())])
}
```

```html
<div class="overview">
  <div class="userSide">
    <h4>User:</h4><span> 2</span>
    <img id="userImg" src="img/paper.png" style="width: 220px; height: 220px;">
  </div>
  <div class="compSide">
    <h4>CPU:</h4><span> 2</span>
    <img id="compImg" src="img/paper.png" style="width: 220px; height: 220px;">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="userBTN">
  <button id="rock">Rock</button>
  <button id="paper">Paper</button>
  <button id="scissors">Scissors</button>
</div>
```

Instead of adding 3 separate event listeners, I'm adding only one, on their parent. In the listener, I'm getting the `id` from the currently clicked target. If the `id` is there (if the click wasn't outside any of the buttons) and if it's contained in the `images` array, I'm getting the image url based on the button's `id`.

Another improvement is the *"images"* array no longer keeps images, but strings referencing the image names.
I added a helper function which creates urls from the image names, by suffixing with `.png` and prefixing with `img/`.
The usefulness of this is that if, for example, you decide to change the folder of the images later on, instead of having to change code in 6 different places, you only have to change it in one place.
And it's not even about this particular implementation. It's about the principle:

Don't repeat yourself. Or: *write **DRY** code*.

Here's the same code, but I modified the `makeImageUrl` function to return images from lorem picsum. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a more suggestive image for scissors.

```js
const images = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];

const loremPicsumIds = {
   rock: 1049,
   paper: 1073,
   scissors: 23
}

const makeImageUrl = id => `https://picsum.photos/id/${loremPicsumIds[id]}/200/200`;

document.querySelector('.userBTN').addEventListener('click', e => {
  const id = e.target.closest('button')?.id;
  if (id && images.includes(id)) {
    userImg.src = makeImageUrl(id);
    cpuPick();
  }
})

function cpuPick() {
  compImg.src = makeImageUrl(images[Math.floor(images.length * Math.random())])
}

[compImg, userImg]
  .forEach(el => el.src = makeImageUrl('paper'))
```

```css
.overview {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="overview">
  <div class="userSide">
    <h4>User:</h4><span> 2</span>
    <img id="userImg" src="">
  </div>
  <div class="compSide">
    <h4>CPU:</h4><span> 2</span>
    <img id="compImg" src="">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="userBTN">
  <button id="rock">Rock</button>
  <button id="paper">Paper</button>
  <button id="scissors">Scissors</button>
</div>
```

Comment: How did you manage to write code this clean, I just started recently and don't understand half the syntax you wrote. Was it like youtube tutorials or practice?

Comment: @kiro, don't worry, with practice comes experience. keep at it, you're doing great. Ref your question: not so much, I've started about a decade ago and there weren't so many great tutorials around. Let's say I've spent a lot of time in browser consoles, looking at objects :). Luckily, you don't have to, anymore :). One great resource for figuring out CSS, HTML and JS is [MDN Web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/). I can't recommend it enough. The great thing about it, as compared to the official standard, is that they are beginner friendly.